# BPMN - possible but not necessarily arriving tasks- Which Gateway

Tags: process, modeling, bpmn, signavio

Which gateway should I use to describe a possibly, but not necessarily arriving task?
The following screenshot demonstrates the situation: [image: BPMN example diagram]

Which gateway can explain after the main department did the Task A, that 
everyone (`Supporter 1`, `Supporter 2`, and `Supporter 3`) can help, but does not have to?

Is the **exclusive** gateway the correct one?

Comment: An exclusive gateway is **exclusive**. Only one outgoing flow can be followed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of a gateway you're looking for is Inclusive Gateway. As described in [BPMN Poster](http://www.bpmb.de/images/BPMN2_0_Poster_EN.pdf)

> **Inclusive Gateway**
>   When splitting, *one or more branches are activated*. All active incoming branches must complete before merging.

Note also that the message receiving intermediate gateway is used to show communication with other pools, but not inside one pool.

I would also recommend using merging gateway, especially when using the gateway with such specific behaviour.

Your diagram could look like this

[image: Inclusive gateway example]